# How can I run setInterval ajax call only when signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I've implemented auto reload of counting number unread.
It gives back the number of messages unread every 15 secs.
But it does the same even when user is not signed in.

How can I stop this? I want do that only when the user is signed in.

I have js like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    refreshPartial();
    setInterval(refreshingPartial, 15000)
});


function refreshingPartial() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/messages/refreshing_partial",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "script",
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use inline js

```
<% if current_user %>
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            refreshPartial();
            setInterval(refreshingPartial, 15000)
        });


        function refreshingPartial() {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/messages/refreshing_partial",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "script",
          });
        }
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

OR

Add a class to body if user signed in and control the class.

```
<body class="<%= "logged-in" if current_user %>">

</body>
```

and change your js little bit

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  if ($("body").is(".signed-in")) { 
    refreshPartial();
    setInterval(refreshingPartial, 15000)
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `refreshPartial` js script should render only if a user is signed in. Following should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        <% if is_user_signed_in %>
            refreshPartial();
            setInterval(refreshingPartial, 15000);

            function refreshingPartial() {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "/messages/refreshing_partial",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "script",
                });
            }
        <% end %>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can't check session variables directly in js. Js is already precompiled.

Comment: Do you notice the enclosing script tag? In a .erb file, this should work perfectly. The script would be compiled only after the document has been rendered. And refreshPartial() method would be executed only if user is signed in. Let me know what issue you're facing with this.